# Is there any performance issues regarding using C++ WinRT Component or a C++ XAML project directly?

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm building a C# XAML application that uses a WINRT Component to access some OpenCV features. Is it possible to access this OpenCV directly from a C++ XAML project? Will it improve the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use third party C++ libraries from a C++ XAML project (however building them can get tricky, I have no experience with OpenCV).

And **interoping** between the C# and C++ components has some performance overhead, but in practical situations it is almost always negligible. It also depends on *how many times* you call your C++ component from the C# app, but you can easily measure the overhead of that on the C# side by calling a fake C++ function (that returns some hard coded value) a million times and measuring the time it takes with a `Stopwatch`.